# .htaccess mod rewrite issue under xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, silex

I installed silex on my xampp installation.

I use the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Test/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When i access

```
http://localhost/Test/web
```

i get the expected output, but when i access

```
http://localhost/Test
```

i will get the following error from silex

> NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /Test/"

The route is there of course. It seems that it thinks that i want to access the route "/Test" instead of "/". Any idea why the folder is still passed, even though i have set the according rewrite base in the .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `.htaccess` file in the webroot folder, for example `localhost/myapp/` and use `FallbackResource /myapp/web/index.php`.

Take a look to the Webserver Configuration documentation:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html